# How to check on initials with html pattern?

Tags: html, regex, database

I'm making a database where you can insert customers.

By the initials of every forename I want to check if it's in the right order.
I want it as: "T.L.R." with the dots between every initial.

To check this, I want to use a pattern.

What I got now is this:

`<input required="true" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}+\.[A-Za-z]{1}+\.[A-Za-z]{1}+\.">`

This code doesn't do anything.
Does anyone know the answer?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: so...how are you planning on supporting someone who has more or less than 3 initials? Suggestion: [stop trying to validate names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining `{1}` which means exactly 1, and `+` which means 1 or more. That does not work.

Try this:

```
[A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z]\.
```

Since `[]` by default already means exactly 1, you can also drop the `{1}`

This does mean that you need exactly 3 characters in your initials, so `I.K.` will not count.

If you want to use 1 character, followed by a dot, and that repeated you can use this:

```
([A-Za-z]\.)+
```

Also, don't forget to add the prefix `^` a postfix `$` to match the whole string:

```
^([A-Za-z]\.)+$
```

Comment: Thanx, That's the answer. I thought the '+' was to add more ;).

Answer (score 0):

As some have said, the regex pattern should be rewritten to

```
[A-Za-z]{1}\.[A-Za-z]{1}\.[A-Za-z]{1}\.
```

The required pattern works well when using a form tag. Try:

```
<form action="customer">
  Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}\.[A-Za-z]{1}\.[A-Za-z]{1}\." title="A.B.C.">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your regex should be like this if you want every character capital with dots in between

```
> /[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\./g
```